# PDO Prepared Statement: Fetch NULL instead of the expected Result

Tags: php, pdo, mariadb, prepared-statement

i don't get the Problem. I have in PHP a SQL Query. If i fire the query via PDO and prepared statements, but without placeholders, i get my expected result. But the product ID in the query comes from outside, so i will replace it with a placeholder :productID. If I do this, i get NULL as a result.

**SQL Query:**

```
SELECT 
COUNT(`stock`.`product`) AS COUNT,
`product`.`name_en` AS NAME,
`product`.`default_consumption` AS `DEFAULT_CONSUM`
FROM `stock`
RIGHT JOIN `product`
ON `stock`.`product` = `product`.`id`
WHERE `product` = :productId
```

If I replace the placeholder :productId with a valid ID in the database table (for example 1) i get my expected result.

```
$query = "SELECT 
          COUNT(`stock`.`product`) AS COUNT,
          `product`.`name_en` AS NAME,
          `product`.`default_consumption` AS `DEFAULT_CONSUM`
          FROM `stock`
          RIGHT JOIN `product`
          ON `stock`.`product` = `product`.`id`
          WHERE `product` = 1";
$query = $this->db->prepare($query);
$query->execute();
$response = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
var_dump($response);
```

**Output**

```
array(3) {
  ["COUNT"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["NAME"]=>
  string(6) "butter"
  ["DEFAULT_CONSUM"]=>
  string(3) "0.1"
}
```

Now i will replace it:

```
$query = "SELECT 
          COUNT(`stock`.`product`) AS COUNT,
          `product`.`name_en` AS NAME,
          `product`.`default_consumption` AS `DEFAULT_CONSUM`
          FROM `stock`
          RIGHT JOIN `product`
          ON `stock`.`product` = `product`.`id`
          WHERE `product` = :productId";

$query = $this->db->prepare($query);
$query->execute(array(':productId' => $productId));
$response = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
var_dump($response);
```

**Output**

```
array(3) {
  ["COUNT"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["NAME"]=>
  NULL
  ["DEFAULT_CONSUM"]=>
  NULL
}
```

$productId is a value from outside. In my test i set it to 1, like in my first example. I get the result NULL for the to fields `DEFAULT_CONSUM` and `name`
If i set the ID 1 direct in the execute():

```
$query->execute(array(':productId' => 1));
```

I get NULL again. If i replace the :productId in the query again to the direct ID of 1, i get the espected result again. I don't get the problem at the moment.

I work with PHP 8.0 and MariaDB. The code above runs in a seperated function. There is in the moment no other code executed.

Thanks for your help. I sure, i'm overlooking something.

**CREATE TABLE**

```
CREATE TABLE`product`(
    `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'ID of the Product',
    `name_en` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Name of the Product in Englisch',
    `name_de` VARCHAR(255) NULL COMMENT 'Name of the Product in German',
    `name_fr` VARCHAR(255) NULL COMMENT 'Name of the Product in France',
    `group` INT(10) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT 1 COMMENT 'ID of the Product Group',
    `unit` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 1 COMMENT 'Id of the Unit',
    `default_consumption` FLOAT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.5 COMMENT 'Value for Default Consumption',
    `created_at` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT 'Timestamp of creation Time',
    `changed_at` TIMESTAMP NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT 'Timestamp of changed',
    `deleted_at` TIMESTAMP NULL COMMENT 'Timestamp of deleted',
    PRIMARY KEY(`id`),
    INDEX `product_name_en_idx`(`name_en`),
    INDEX `product_name_de_idx`(`name_de`),
    INDEX `product_name_fr_idx`(`name_fr`),
    INDEX `product_group_idx`(`group`),
    CONSTRAINT `product_group_fk` 
        FOREIGN KEY(`group`)
        REFERENCES `product_group`(`id`)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE SET NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT `product_unit_fk` 
        FOREIGN KEY(`unit`)
        REFERENCES `unit`(`id`)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE RESTRICT
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `stock`(
    `product` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'ID of the Product',
    `user` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'ID of the User',
    `stock` FLOAT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT 'Stock Value',
    `individual_consumption` FLOAT(10) UNSIGNED NULL COMMENT 'Individual Consumption Value',
    `ki_value` FLOAT(10) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT 0.000 COMMENT 'KI Up Down Value',
    `last_buy` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT 'Timestmap of last Buy',
    INDEX `stock_product_idx`(`product`),
    INDEX `stock_user_idx`(`user`),
    CONSTRAINT `stock_product_fk`
        FOREIGN KEY(`product`)
        REFERENCES `product`(`id`)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE RESTRICT,
    CONSTRAINT `stock_user_fk`
        FOREIGN KEY(`user`)
        REFERENCES `user`(`id`)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE RESTRICT
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: what result does it return if you write it as `WHERE product = '1'`?

Comment: @YourCommonSense I get the result NULL. I tried to intval():
`$query->execute(array(':productId' => intval($productId)))`
No, change.

Comment: well then it's a very rare case where string value doesn't match. Then you need to use bindValue instead of array in execute. I don't really understand your query though.

Comment: though I still have a feeling that your first observation is not correct

Comment: It will work with bindValue! Thanks! Can you explain me, why it doesn't work in my way or have you some link where i can read it. 
Why do you think my first obervation is not correct?

Comment: The example says it all. Some people say that providing the data using wrong datatype yields wrong results. But until this day I never seen it in the wild. Sending array into execute explicitly binds a value as string, making it `'1'`. Hence your question is rather why `WHERE product = 1` gives the result and `WHERE product = '1'` doesn't. You may ask this question on some database related stack exchange site. If you do, please share a link here, I am very interested in this particular issue

Comment: Can you share the results of `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for `stock` and `product`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you found a bug with the MariaDB SQL optimizer. Please file a bug report with them at your earliest convenience.

The issue is not related to PDO. The reason why you see a different result is that PDO binds all values as strings by default. When you bind it as string then the comparison in the `WHERE` clause is evaluated properly. When you cast the value to an integer or you use literal 1 then the optimizer compares it to `product.id` instead of `stock.product`. Not really sure what is internally happening here, but clearly the behaviour is wrong when using an integer. You could ask on https://dba.stackexchange.com/ to see if someone has an explanation for this behaviour, but most likely this needs to be addressed by MariaDB team as a bug.

[Here is an online reproducible version of this bug.](https://phpize.online/?phpses=ebf1e7fbbdb08e1c75b24caff2bbf21a&sqlses=b3262ca386ec77d932c4e24a9172fc96&php_version=php8&sql_version=mariadb)